# Push notification on android: IBM MQTT

Tags: android, push, mqtt

I am very new to android environment and have to set up client side using the (wmqtt.jar) sample application given on http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?

I know only about hello world program.

Kindly tell how can I integrate it in my simple android application, step by step.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: download this example [AndroidPushNotificationsDemo using IBM MQTT](https://github.com/tokudu/AndroidPushNotificationsDemo) see maybe helpful

Answer (score 3):

There is a good example and run through at http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599

I'd also point out that you might be better off with the recently released open source Java client. You can find it at http://git.eclipse.org/c/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java.git/ - you should find the licence is much friendlier than for wmqtt.jar.

Answer (score 1):

As Roger says, the best / latest Java client code is that available from the Eclipse Paho project - http://git.eclipse.org/c/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java.git/

The IA92 code and wmqtt.jar has a difficult license and does not support some of the latest features like authentication.

In addition, you will find a lot of useful links and information on the mqtt.org wiki http://mqtt.org/wiki/doku.php/mqtt_on_the_android_platform

Answer (score 0):

Very good sample code available at http://mosquitto.org/files/examples/android-mqtt-example.zip. Once you understand how it works, you would be able to move to writing your own code.