# Send push notifications on android without using C2DM

Tags: android, notifications, push, android-c2dm

Is it possible to send push notifications to an android application without using [Google server: C2DM](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/#server)?

So, I would like to have my own server which sends notifications directly to the app, but I'm not sure how are the notifications perceived by the device, because the device needs to receive notifications even if the app is not running and the notifications should appear in the notification center.

I think that the guys from [www.airpush.com](http://www.airpush.com) have managed to this, but I'm not sure how.

Can anyone help me with this please?

UPDATE:

Also I would like to know how to display the notifications in the notification center if I don't use C2DM? And if it is possible to configure the notification center to receive notifications from my server even if the user deletes the application developed by us, application which registered that device to receive notifications.

I want to send 3-4 notifications a day, but these notifications need to appear in the notification center and they should go only through our server. How can I configure the notification center within the app to make requests on my server for push notifications.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the FAQ on airpush.com, they're not using real push notifications but rather polling the server a few times per day.  One reason I think this is a viable solution for you as well is that Android's C2DM apparently makes use of the Google Play Store, so it won't work on devices distributed outside of the Google eco-system.  With over 5 Million Kindle Fires having sold already, that is worth thinking about.

From Airpush FAQ:

> When executed once from the main activity of an Android™ application, the Airpush client utilizes Android™ OS's AlarmManager framework to schedule ongoing server polling events a few times per day. If an ad is polled from the server it is cached until optimal display time, which is algorithmically determined by the server.

Comment: Yes, this could be a solution, but what I was wondering is how to display the notifications in the notification center if I don't use C2DM? Also I was wondering if it is possible to configure the notification center to receive notifications from my server even if the user deletes the application.

Comment: If you do polling in a background service or if you register a BroadcastReceiver in the AlarmManager (the latter is probably how Airpush does it), you will have everything you need to send a notification to the notification center.  All you need is an instance of Context (which BroadcastReceiver.onReceive takes as an argument, so you're good there) and the NotificationManager which you can get from the Context mentioned above.  With those two things, you can create a notification and the PendingIntent that launches an activity when the notification is clicked.

Comment: Yes, but this works only if the application is in background. If the user closes the application using a task manager or from settings the AlarmManager's methods won't be called anymore. Also I think that the AlarmManger is not working if the device is asleep. Basically this solution would work only if the application is open or in background and the device is not asleep, so pretty little time.

Comment: Not true.  I have an app where the alarm is a central feature, and in my testing I would shut the app down with a Task Killer and confirm that the AlarmManager would wake my app up.  When you register a PendingIntent with the AlarmManager, it's managed by the OS and not your app.

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution from UrbanAirship called [Helium push](https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%3a+Android%3a+Helium+Push). According documentation Helium:

> Works on Android 1.6 and higher
>       Does not require a Google Account
>       No default pushes per day limit
>       No default pushes per minute limit
>       Works on Amazon devices (e.g., Kindle Fire)
>       End to end Urban Airship support (i.e., API to to device)
>       Best throughput

The problem is that you need development app key for using this one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I would prefer to use only my server on this.

Comment: The actual question is, as I understand, `How do they do it?` :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/):

> MQTT stands for MQ Telemetry Transport. It is a publish/subscribe, extremely simple and lightweight messaging protocol, designed for constrained devices and low-bandwidth, high-latency or unreliable networks.

It can be used (and was used in some applications) to implement custom server push solutions. One of the most well known applications using MQTT is [Facebook Messanger](http://mqtt.org/2011/08/mqtt-used-by-facebook-messenger).

You can easily find more information on MQTT in the Internet, e.g. [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006533/push-notification-on-android-ibm-mqtt) or [in this blog post](http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/).

Answer (score 0):

Without using C2DM there's not option for a "real push notification". Because (afaik, correct me if I'm wrong) an android device registers at google (they can still deinstall malware from your phone via remote) and with this ip they are able to do a push notification. All other solutions could tend to be a "register at a server, keep the connection alive and wait for requests" or something and tend to be more battery-inefficient.

Comment: We want to send only 3-4 notifications a day, but we want them in the notification center and if it is possible we want them there even if the user deletes the app developed by us.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to only receive 3-4 messages per day and your messages are not bound to specific arrival times, you don't need pushing mechanisms.
Just create a service in your app that checks your own web service 5-10 times a day. If there is new data, make your app display it in the notification center.
If you don't want to have a service running all the time (like many messaging apps do), you can set up alarms (using the Android AlarmManager framework) that wake your app up regularily to check for new messages to display.

> And if it is possible to configure the notification center to receive
>   notifications from my server even if the user deletes the application
>   developed by us, application which registered that device to receive
>   notifications.

That sounds like you want to write a virus or root kit ;-) You could use e-mails for your messages instead.

UPDATE 2013-12-30:
As just noted in my comment, rebuilding what GCM does is not a nice approach. It's enough when Google Services already load the device with this functionality. If your goal is just that Google does not see what messages you send to your users, you might aswell encrypt them. For Google not being able to actually read your messages, the client app should generate a key and send it to your server. All messages you send via GCM can then be encrypted using that key.

If you just want to circumvent Google's restriction on the amount of messages sent to users, you could pack multiple messages into one GCM notification and show them one after the other. But then again, we are back at some kind of polling solution as described before, with the exception that the user does not need to have internet access when you want to show the messages as they are cached on the device.

Comment: This solution is not actually a `push`. Its just a mare server polling. But I would appreciate this as a solution to the actual problem, if the number of messages to be pushed every day is in single digits.

Comment: You're right, it does not provide the requested solution, but rather an easier (and in my opinion fitting) solution for the given problem. Funny I learned that airpush does it the same way I described.
You don't want to rebuild GCM yourself. In the end for real-time events you'd need to do that, i.e. be connected to your own service all the time. It's enough load on the battery when Google Play Services already do that.

Answer (score 0):

Parse has an excellent push notification service for Android, very easy to setup. More info here: [Parse Android Notification Doc](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#push)

Comment: But OP's question clearly says he has to use his own backend server.